# ArrayIndexoutofboundException

Tags: android, adapter, indexoutofboundsexception, picasso

Iam receving below error
 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=55; index=55.
The application is crashing after some images are scrolled down could you  please suggest where i need to make changes

```
        import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

        import android.content.Context;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
        import android.widget.GridView;
        import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    int imageTotal = 70;
    public static String[] mThumbIds = {
    "http://www.fashionlady.in/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/creative-punjabi-mehndi-design-2016.jpg",
    "http://scraps99.com/main/post_images/Mehndi-Design/Mehndi-Design_151.jpg",
    "http://stylesatlife.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Ganesha-Chaturthi.jpg",
    "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/0a/05/12/0a05120d03dbe15f66eb8c97c085d25c.jpg",
    "http://srivinayagacatering.com/cook/upload/media/youtube_O9e0MZkXNxM.jpg",
    "http://stylesatlife.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Ganesha-Design-For-Hand.jpg",
    "http://i.ethnicoapp.com/m/cOHL4_xuEP_99VVgLId-xD-Eyi7ktW4U8Ph7zi9GczJ6wQbrdHGhqi8yJi0TD3Loee_9_AV_386I7ym1VbImCkqhQZe53CeasIRvy8CItTlcooEvmyPFtenxNUNGHtOFYWJjZGVmZ2hiY2RlZmVmZw,,/ganesha-mehendi-design-1461583969.jpg",
    "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/b6/95/44/b69544f3ab5e92a4e723e0017985a26b.jpg",
    "http://thestylecircle.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Organic-abstracts.jpg",
    "http://www.fashionlady.in/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Ganesh-Mehndi-Design1.jpg",
    "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/62/b6/c8/62b6c82d7d022f1fc6f1352c649263cd.jpg",
    "http://i.ethnicoapp.com/m/ao0TV_479pabydo3Al6jF8hNvORkvgC50AYfaZ2pymLoGtEN8Z5u1E7aRPbDsPKMnbGvBUhWipKqcyJ2qppTW0UhVCoqErG4AFTaS5Jwl_ntqN-3qq8eMjaYtlNzXLCJYWJjZGVmZ2hiY2RlZmVmZw,,/mehandi-design-57caf6c3952c2.jpg",
    "http://67.media.tumblr.com/41e8e1f6271b1350faa387eb097270c9/tumblr_nv8amk46Pn1qdlbsvo1_1280.jpg",
    "https://www.stylishandtrendy.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/ganesha-mehndi-designs.png",
    "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/f4/f2/36/f4f2362a195833e10b2ad77a17ae4b0d.jpg", "http://i.ethnicoapp.com/m/ZPkNdGld1RNi2p-Iw8e8bj5TGGCKeVx3QRzCh7bc_cWFlN3LvmYlBSaLCgFeS3PB_Y2LBrOwDkCZCsSHpHByavSVh7_Z3d3wEXHWehIJotXpx57SipEsOFYvdGBsvm3OYWJjZGVmZ2hiY2RlZmVmZw,,/simple-mehndi-design-576176bc176cb.jpg",
    "http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-WX4WDgL4Q1w/UXJWD_gp9NI/AAAAAAAAAW8/xIKhBR4T5-w/s400/Latest-And-Simple-Arabic-Mehndi-Designs-For-Hands-2012-8.jpg",
    "http://www.ozyle.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Beautiful-Bridle-Mehndi-Designs-4.jpg",
    "http://img.thebridalbox.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/A-Bouquet-Of-Beauty-pakistani-arabic-mehndi-designs.jpg",
    "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/9a/bf/99/9abf99999c494045bf8965b64493e2ce.jpg",
    "http://fashionspk.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/New-Eid-Henna-Mehndi-Collection-2013-Female-Fashion-Designs-1-450x214.jpg",
    "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-8bC4hSwfNcs/VArSX5kIg9I/AAAAAAAAGgs/AiQoxDeTnE0/s1600/0d424e3a3846cd33652611cf018583b5.jpg",
    "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/ed/4e/74/ed4e74c785378455236cb69063e8154b.jpg",
    "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-pdEQcpmOJtc/Va84R8uMpkI/AAAAAAAABD8/LJqXlQsySts/w800-h800/ba3.jpg",
    "https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-jzDRz30YAcA/V5affkyTIYI/AAAAAAAAB_o/bxzCpQvi5QM_GoRDWLWcA-sabZAHOCV3QCLcB/s640/20%2Bbest%2Bidea%2Babout%2Bmehndi%2Bdesigns%2Blatest%2Bfor%2Bhands%2B3.jpg",
    "https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-RmtccTBjD0U/VzxaKHYPE2I/AAAAAAAAHKI/IX2YSTcLGGkll_dte1re9M1PCBrWV50CwCKgB/s1600/henna-arabic-mehndi-designs-2015-16.jpg",
    "http://todayfashion.pk/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Latest-Finger-Mehndi-Designs-Collection-2016-For-Girls-5.jpeg",
    "http://pakifashion.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Arabic-Mehndi-Design-For-Eid-5.jpg",
    "http://pakistaniladies.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Beautiful-Latest-Henna-Mehndi-Designs-for-Bride-Hands-Images-2015-Trends-2014-Pakistan-India-Banladesh-Srilanka-Facebook-pinterest-Collections.jpg",
    "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/54/0d/32/540d32cb066fac59a665d555b7b4e791.jpg",
    "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/09/d3/16/09d316cae4667de5fc043d61a6f45c30.jpg",
    "http://www.mehmehndi.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/10-Easy-Simple-Arabic-Mehndi-Designs-For-Hands-In-2015-7.jpg",
    "http://stylespk.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Mehndi-Designs-collection-2013-9.jpg",
    "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/87/ec/c1/87ecc185dfeed84eb4b52378862ac749.jpg",
    "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/2b/0c/7f/2b0c7fdeacd199581da22042f949dd15.jpg",
    "http://fashioninbox.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Latest-Arabic-Eid-Mehndi-designs-2015-6.jpg",
    "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/8d/5b/ad/8d5bada1d6f7c83d804be2506bcf2541.jpg",
    "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/aa/68/fb/aa68fb77c63c66bdfd236ef2b2d3c14e.jpg",
    "http://i0.wp.com/mehndidesignimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/back-hand-half-side-arabic-mehndi-design.jpg",
    "http://easyday.snydle.com/files/2014/02/easy-arabic-mehandi-designs.jpg",
    "http://www.mymehndidesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Simple-Mehndi-Designs6.jpg",
    "http://kfoods.com/article/images/mehandi-design-07-01.jpeg",
    "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/4a/d4/04/4ad404abc0359eaa9b605f52f83f0744.jpg",
    "https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-NG9rOvpHAlM/VyYS3zFyHYI/AAAAAAAADWQ/u_M1a9iOu3Ydj-vtJ_qPjf9iUW1IObByACLcB/s1600/New%2BStylish%2BMehndi%2BDesigns-22.jpg",
    "http://www.mehndidesign.net/wp-content/uploads/Indian-Hands-Mehndi-Designs.jpg",
    "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/cb/3f/f3/cb3ff31c393bb689ca769d32627f09ea.jpg",
    "http://www.mymehndidesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/10-Best-and-Beautiful-Mehndi-Designs-for-Girls-Easyday6.jpg",
    "http://www.abeautyclub.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Finger-Eid-Mehndi-Designs-2016-For-Girls1-650x740.jpg",
    "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/68/7a/f1/687af13aff8c06615a09093ee9523b8d.jpg",
    "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/8b/7d/44/8b7d44fe8579ba677a568a3a14dc1fb5.jpg",
    "http://topmehndidesigns.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Beautiful-Best-Simple-Arabic-Mehndi-Designs-for-Hands-2016-2017-Indian-Pakistani.jpg",
    "http://pakistaniladies.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/New-Latest-Simple-Arabic-Eid-Mehndi-Designs-2016-2017-for-Hands-Indian-Pakistani-13.jpg",
    "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/VjMyNU5ozh4/hqdefault.jpg",
    "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/1200x/21/07/ef/2107ef2ff18c98a4dd2b8b370ed2a4f0.jpg",
    "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-eG7EHfBDoeA/VS-qp3VwnMI/AAAAAAAACmk/Kx8lIJIL-lo/s1600/New-arabic-mehndi-design-2015-2.jpg",
    "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/93/89/5a/93895a42aa904fe91c2f5d7f258e3efe.jpg",
    "http://topmehndidesigns.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Simple-Fancy-Beautiful-Arabic-Bridal-Mehndi-Design-for-Hands-2016-2017-9.jpg",
    "http://www.listfunda.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/2015-eid-mehndi-design-for-hands.jpg",
    "http://www.mymehndidesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Stylish-Mehndi-Designs-2016-For-Bridal-Wedding-Eid-Party5.jpg",
    "http://ytimg.googleusercontent.com/vi/WhjvVcrOeSE/mqdefault.jpg",
    "http://kms.ounousa.com/Content/ResizedImages/548/10000/inside/150810104225116.jpg",
    "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/19/63/9a/19639ae45916bb8a6491aa28ff0599d8.jpg",
    "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/c6/02/c1/c602c14135d4c7f95b54c97c6a43ec29.jpg",
    "http://s7.postimg.org/9cxe0c0az/1291_647590481918937_1366870647_n.jpg",
    "http://interestingmagazine.in/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/13686631_1751943998377719_2471147301102863183_n.jpg",



    };

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return imageTotal;
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(480, 480));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        String url = getItem(position);
        Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(url)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.loader)
                .fit()
                .centerCrop().into(imageView);
        return imageView;
    }
}
```

Im getting this Error which is

```
  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=55; index=55
                                                                        at com.shirisha.mehandi.ImageAdapter1.getItem(ImageAdapter1.java:86)
                                                                        at com.shirisha.mehandi.ImageAdapter1.getView(ImageAdapter1.java:104)
                                                                        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:3065)
                                                                        at android.widget.GridView.makeAndAddView(GridView.java:1463)
```

Any Help please...

Comment: you `mThumbIds` have only 54 items and you are trying to access 55th item which is not present

Comment: Actually it has 55 items - see `length`. Arrays are zero indexed, however, so index 55 is actually the 56th item.

Answer (score 1):

Change the method `getCount()` into:

```
public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length();
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: In terms of a little more detail, the adapter is configured to think it has `imageTotal` items, which in your code is 70. However, it actually only has 55 items (the contents of `mThumbIds`). So when it attempts to reach for the 56th item, which doesn't exist, it fails.

Answer (score 1):

It is because Arrays in java start from index `0` to index `array.length-1` if length of array is 55 then last index of the array to be looped in should be 54.
This change will help you.

```
public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length();
}
```

Comment: True, but this is simply the symptom, not the cause. The cause is that the adapter thinks it has more items than it actually does, which is why it's trying to access the 56th item in the array (which doesn't exist). See jos's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an Array. Then you will run into its 2 values that don't quite match up; Length and Index. Example:

```
ArrayList<String> my_array = new ArrayList<String>();
// Add stuff to it.
my_array.add("Ajeet");
my_array.add("Harry");
my_array.add("Chaitanya");
my_array.add("Steve");
my_array.add("Anuj");
```

At this point, my_array has a length of 5, but the last, "Anuj", has Index 4. So when you ask for the last item in an Array, you will have to use something like:

```
String last = my_array.get(my_array.length - 1);
```